# Python, парсинг значения с использованием переменной в регулярном выражении

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Язык Python, помогите пожалуйста с парсингом значения из строки.

Имеется переменная с типом данных <class 'list'>, с таким значением:

```py
tickers = [{'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '21337.84000000'}, {'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'price': '0.00244900'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '52.40000000'}]
```

На самом деле в строке намного больше валютных пар и цен, я укоротил строку.
Значение переменной `tickers` обновляется раз в секунду и значения валютных пар могут меняться местами, это сайт их так может отдавать, в итоге значение переменной `tickers` может выглядеть так:

```py
[{'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'price': '0.00244900'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '52.40000000'}, {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '21337.84000000'}]
```

или например так:

```py
[{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '52.40000000'}, {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '21337.84000000'}, {'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'price': '0.00244900'}]
```

Есть задача получить значение цены для определенной валютной пары, записанной в переменной

```py
para= "BTCUSDT"
```

Переменная со списком para используется в цикле for, значения переменной меняются

Как проще, регуляркой или `json` или еще как то, получить значение `21337.84000000` для пары  `BTCUSDT` подставляя значение с валютной парой из переменной para

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install jmespath`

```py
import jmespath as jp

data = [{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '52.40000000'},
        {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '21337.84000000'},
        {'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'price': '0.00244900'}]
para = "BTCUSDT"
pricepara = float(
    jp.search(
        f"[?symbol=='{para}'].price | [0]",
        data
    ) or 'NaN'
)

print(pricepara)

# 21337.84
```

Comment: @Dimych, Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

т.е. основная проблема как в ваш код вместо "[?symbol=='BTCUSDT'].price | [0]",
Подставить вместо BTCUSDT значение из переменной, примерно так:

мне нужно немного по другому, но почему то не работает

```
data = [{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '52.40000000'}, {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '21337.84000000'},
        {'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'price': '0.00244900'}]
        
para = "BTCUSDT"

pricepara = float(
    jp.search(
        "[?symbol=='para'].price | [0]",
        data
    ) or 'NaN'
)

print(pricepara)
```

Comment: Поправил свой ответ. Теперь должно быть то, что Вам требуется

Answer (score 0):

> помогите пожалуйста с парсингом значения из строки

> Имеется переменная с типом данных <class 'list'>

так у вас строка или список?

если это список словарей (как в примере) то можно еще вынуть нужное значение через вспомогательный словарь:

```
para = "BTCUSDT"
data = [{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '52.40000000'},
        {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '21337.84000000'},
        {'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'price': '0.00244900'}]

pares = {i['symbol']:float(i['price']) for i in data}
print(pares.get(para))  # 21337.84
```